# External hard-drive inaccessible for PC

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate HD 250GB (external USB, GoFlex).  It is about year old wasn't used often.

I can't see or access this disk after I connect it to my Windows 7 PC. I also tried other PCs with no luck.

When I run DriveDetect I can see it on drivers list: "FreeAgent GoFlex". The BIOS does see it as well. Also I can see and access this drive when I connect it to my TV!

What can I do?

Comment: On how many other PCs did you try connecting that drive to?

Comment: Does it show up under Disk Management? If so, see if you can right-click and assign a drive letter to it.

Comment: about 6 different PCs. It shows up on my laptop Disk Manager as UNALLOCATED, whereas on a Windows 8 PC as RAW.

Comment: It had files on it but I connected it to a Toshiba TV as an external storage device and I think it has removed the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see your files on the Toshiba TV, connect that to your network and access the files over the network from whatever PC you like.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the antivirus is inhibiting a program on the drive from working.  Some antivirus programs also cause the right click in Windows Explorer to display different options.  I am guessing you meant to say that the computer BIOS can see the drive.  With my Tower, if I plug a drive into the USB ports on the back of the tower, the OS might handle them differently.

I am guessing that you are using some version of Windows. For a Mac one must also install the program to write to a NTFS drive, while current native Mac will read NTFS.

Comment: The OS doesn't discriminate as such with the position of the USB ports, not atleast if they are of the same kind.

Comment: if somebody's been lazy with the internal cabling, some of the front USB ports may not actually be connected - so trying to connect via the back ports could possibly make a difference.